# How to identify which type of popup

Tags: selenium-webdriver

When I try to enter icicibank.com website, a popup appears.
Which type of popup is it and how can it be handled using selenium.
I have checked for confirmation popup, but the options it has are "later", "allow".

Answer (score 0):

This is not kind of alert that created with `JavaScript` `confirm()` method, 
 but a simple `HTML` element, so you cannot use alert confirmation in this case... You can handle it with common `Selenium` `click()` method.

You can find mentioned buttons with `XPath` like below:

```
//div[@id="push-modal-close"] # for "LATER" button
//a[text()="Allow"] # for "ALLOW" button
```

You didn't mention your programming language, so here is `Python` example:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[text()="Allow"]').click()
```

Comment: Thanks Andersson,Will try this